# if I use .NET Framework for my application, do I have to pay anything to Microsoft?

Tags: .net, microsoft

I am planning to develop an enterprise application using .NET Framework. I will sell that application to other companies. Do I have to make any payment to Microsoft, like royalties or something else?

Comment: Pay them some respect. It is a great framework. Other than that, nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Applications written using .Net library do not require payment to Microsoft in any form.

*(The fact that usually .Net apps will run on Windows, generally ensures Microsoft sales of their OS.)*

Comment: and what if i use visual studio 2010

Comment: It makes no difference, except you pay for VS 2010 too.

Comment: You can even create Commercial projects using the Express editions of Visual Studio (if they meet your needs)...

Comment: @Dhaval - I think In silico (now deleted comment) was because he was confused by your question, it is as if you'd expect to pay  royalties to MS for a novel you'd written using Microsoft Word.