# I want to sell my software [C# desktop application] but I was Stuck in licencing

Tags: open-source, microsoft, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [if I use .NET Framework for my application, do I have to pay anything to Microsoft?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89944/if-i-use-net-framework-for-my-application-do-i-have-to-pay-anything-to-microso)

I have developed a desktop application called "Institute Management System" which has modules like Class manager, Subject manager, Topics manager, Student inquiry manager Student admission manager, Fees manager, Exam manager etc. using C# for the front end and MS Access for the back end.

The main problem is that I want to sell it and earn some money but I heard that my application needs to be registered at Microsoft, and I would have to get a license from them for selling, and have to pay them money too. I have spent four months developing it at my own expense, and worked very hard to develop it.

So I want some tips, advice, any suggestion for the same. Please also tell me the procedure for all of the required registrations and payment issues.

And I also want to ask you if you **Can you suggest any other technology where I develop my application and sell it without worrying about licencing and related issues?**

I am now more confused about that "MS technology is open source or not? "

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89944/if-i-use-net-framework-for-my-application-do-i-have-to-pay-anything-to-microso

Comment: Where did you hear that application need to be registered at Microsoft? As far as I know you don't need a license for a normal desktop application

Comment: Thank u sir, I got some relief now,but others[xyz] told me that vs and ms access is not free so your app is also not free,so you have to pay some money to them[ms].

Comment: That's a straight lie. Yes, the full version of Visual Studio costs money (but there is the Express version which is free) but that doesn't have anything to do with whether you make your application free or not.

Comment: There's even a free Access Runtime you can use - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=4438 (2007 version)

Comment: Someone has just made a fool out of you. You can make anything, sell anything. Microsoft has nothing to deal with you or any developer. They just provide the tools and have nothing to deal with your project. It's just like carpenter tools. You never register your chair with the tool manufacturer before selling it.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay without being a fool you never learn or achieve ,today I got convocation with great people like ChrisF and found new and most valuable and helpful web site tooo.

Comment: @SurendraSoni , fool out of you doesn't meant i am referring you as a fool. It's just a proverb which meant that someone lied to you. You don't need to feel offended as i never offend anyone in rarest of case

Comment: Ohhh it's oky dude I never mind it.But being a fool is more **Important**